# Was Pirates of Dark Water ever completed?

Tags: the-pirates-of-dark-water

I remember an old cartoon from my childhood called [The Pirates of Dark Water](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0101169/).  It was about a planet where an entity made of Black Sludge was destroying the oceans (perhaps a reference to oil spills.)  The main characters were collecting gems to try and stop the creature and save the world.  Oh yeah, and there was a monkey bird.  If this sounds familiar, I was wondering if the show was ever completed or if it is available or can be seen online somewhere.

Comment: wiki says never completed.

Comment: Originally, this was a mini-series done on FOX. It only last about 5 episodes. It was then picked up as a regular series. Sadly, it ended without explenation about about 21 episodes.

Comment: Rats, no hope for an ending?

Comment: @Hoytman - After all this time? Probably not.

Comment: Do you know if there are scripts or comics of the show available?

Answer (score 2):

The show was never completed. The **21 episodes** that were completed were released on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042I6528) in 2010 (to mixed reviews - lots of positive, but also lots of complaints about the disc quality).

However, according to the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Dark_Water#Other_media):

> In November 1991, Marvel Comics produced a comic book series based on
>   the show. Originally intended as a six-part limited series, it was
>   extended to nine issues to include a three-part original story.

The comic books can be found on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OCQTRM) if you are interested.